# ERROR reading large tables using pySpark in EMR cluster using spark.sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-emr

I'm trying to read a table using pySpark with an EMR cluster. I run the same query with tables of different size and num of partitions. I have no problems except for the largest tables (there are areoud 4,500M of records).

I run the simple line: `spark.sql('SELECT * FROM [db].[table_name])`

The error I get is the following:

```
23/05/31 09:58:12 INFO HiveConf: Found configuration file file:/etc/spark/conf.dist/hive-site.xml
23/05/31 09:58:12 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.thrift.url does not exist
23/05/31 09:58:12 INFO AWSGlueClientFactory: Using region from ec2 metadata : eu-west-1
23/05/31 09:58:16 WARN package: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields'.
23/05/31 09:58:18 INFO SQLStdHiveAccessController: Created SQLStdHiveAccessController for session context : HiveAuthzSessionContext [sessionString=cf938f20-04d1-4a89-8ece-0f6ba279d9cc, clientType=HIVECLI]
23/05/31 09:58:18 WARN SessionState: METASTORE_FILTER_HOOK will be ignored, since hive.security.authorization.manager is set to instance of HiveAuthorizerFactory.
23/05/31 09:58:18 INFO AWSCatalogMetastoreClient: Mestastore configuration hive.metastore.filter.hook changed from org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.DefaultMetaStoreFilterHookImpl to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.AuthorizationMetaStoreFilterHook
23/05/31 09:58:18 INFO AWSGlueClientFactory: Using region from ec2 metadata : eu-west-1
23/05/31 09:58:18 INFO AWSGlueClientFactory: Using region from ec2 metadata : eu-west-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 616, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, int_truncate, vertical))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o149.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed while listing partition folders in parallel
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ParallelListExecutor.newFailedListingException(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ParallelListExecutor.awaitResults(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ParallelListExecutor.run(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FastS3PartitionFileLister.doListing(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FastS3PartitionFileLister.$anonfun$tryListing$1(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:643)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FastS3PartitionFileLister.withMetering(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FastS3PartitionFileLister.tryListing(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.$anonfun$bulkListLeafFiles$1(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.withListObserver(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CatalogFileIndex.filterPartitions(CatalogFileIndex.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CatalogFileIndex.listFiles(CatalogFileIndex.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.selectedPartitions$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:265)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.selectedPartitions(DataSourceScanExec.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.dynamicallySelectedPartitions$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:303)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.dynamicallySelectedPartitions(DataSourceScanExec.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.isDataPrefetchSupportedForAllFiles(DataSourceScanExec.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:476)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:471)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.doExecuteColumnar(DataSourceScanExec.scala:690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeColumnar$1(SparkPlan.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeColumnar(SparkPlan.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteColumnar(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:667)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeColumnar$1(SparkPlan.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeColumnar(SparkPlan.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ColumnarToRowExec.inputRDDs(Columnar.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:959)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:209)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:486)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3932)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2904)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3922)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:552)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3920)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$7(SQLExecution.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3920)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2904)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:329)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListObjectsV2Handler
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.list(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:423)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.list.OnlyFilesOrderedListing.getNextPage(OnlyFilesOrderedListing.java:81)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.list.OnlyFilesOrderedListing.next(OnlyFilesOrderedListing.java:71)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.list.OnlyFilesOrderedListing.next(OnlyFilesOrderedListing.java:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListFilesProcessor.$anonfun$doProcess$4(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:465)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:643)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListFilesProcessor.withPageMetering$1(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:457)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListFilesProcessor.doProcess(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:464)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListFilesProcessor.process(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FastS3PartitionFileLister.listPartitionPathSegment(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FastS3PartitionFileLister.$anonfun$createListingTasks$2(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$$anon$2.apply(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ParallelListExecutor$$anon$1.runTask(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ParallelListExecutor$$anon$1.run(FastS3PartitionFileLister.scala:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListObjectsV2Handler
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:181)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListObjectsV2Response(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:355)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsV2Unmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:136)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsV2Unmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:125)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:69)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1794)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleSuccessResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1477)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1384)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5456)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5403)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5397)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjectsV2(AmazonS3Client.java:971)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.ListObjectsV2Call.perform(ListObjectsV2Call.java:26)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.ListObjectsV2Call.perform(ListObjectsV2Call.java:12)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor$CallPerformer.call(GlobalS3Executor.java:111)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:138)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:191)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:186)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.listObjectsV2(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:75)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.list(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:414)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 280; Character reference "&#
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:399)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:326)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1466)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanCharReferenceValue(XMLScanner.java:1339)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3052)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:167)
        ... 49 more
```

I tired to read directly using `pyspark.read.parquet([path])` and I have not encountered any problems.

The problem seems related to list partitions, but I'm not sure about it.

Is there a way to fix the problem?

I have problems reading a large table using spark.sql() but I'm able to read the same table directly from parquet files using spark.read.parquet().

I'd like to read my table using spark.sql().